# Cannot install Mate Desktop

Tags: mate

After installing Mate Desktop `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-core ubuntu-mate-desktop` I got some errors so I run `sudo apt-get -f install` but I got these errors:

```
tomsk@tomsk-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  account-plugin-google
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  account-plugin-google
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
265 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 3 368 B of archives.
After this operation, 29,7 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://sk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 account-plugin-google all 0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1 [3 368 B]
Fetched 3 368 B in 0s (40,5 kB/s)           
(Reading database ... 369938 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../account-plugin-google_0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking account-plugin-google (0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/account-plugin-google_0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service', which is also in package kde-config-telepathy-accounts 4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/account-plugin-google_0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
tomsk@tomsk-VirtualBox:~$
```

So I have problem with package `account-plugin-google`

It is a fresh Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Comment: See here: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/fix-dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-x.html

Comment: Thanks and why is it happening? I had similar problems when I was installing KDE

Comment: Jumping straight to 'force' commands without trying to solve the problem seems unwise without more explanation. `account-plugin-google` conflicts with  `kde-config-telepathy-accounts`. If you are not using one of those, then uninstall it...which will solve the problem.

Comment: i know this not an answer but i suggest you to install clean Ubuntu mate.there is a reason why every distro lunches the separate version for separate desktop environment